# why keras layers initialization doesn't work

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

when i run my small keras model i got this error

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value bn6/beta
     [[{{node bn6/beta/read}} = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

[full traceback error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXX4r.png)

code:

```
"input layer"
command_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,1))
image_measurements_features = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1, 640))
"command module"
command_module_layer1=keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu')(command_input)
command_module_layer2=keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu')(command_module_layer1)
"concatenation layer"
j=keras.layers.concatenate([command_module_layer2,image_measurements_features])
"desicion module"
desicion_module_layer1=keras.layers.Dense(512,activation='relu')(j)
desicion_module_layer2=keras.layers.Dense(256,activation='relu')(desicion_module_layer1)
desicion_module_layer3=keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu')(desicion_module_layer2)
desicion_module_layer4=keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='relu')(desicion_module_layer3)
initt = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(initt)
big_hero_4=keras.models.Model(inputs=[command_input, image_measurements_features], outputs=desicion_module_layer4)
big_hero_4.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
"train the model"
historyy=big_hero_4.fit([x, y],z,batch_size=None, epochs=1,steps_per_epoch=1000)
```

do you have any solutions for this error ? 
Why keras doesn't initialize the layers automatically without using global variables initializer (the error exists before and after adding the global initializer)

Comment: Please include the full traceback of this error.

Comment: i edited the question and added it, thank you

Comment: Why are you using tf.global_variables_initializer and an additional session? That's not required to use Keras at all.

Comment: before adding    "tf.global_variables_initializer"    the error was      "Attempting to use uninitialized value W_c_1"     so i tried to solve the error by adding the global variable initialization

Comment: Then you should make a self-contained example that we can run and reproduces the error. I don't see how or why it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your model and then make and compile it. That's the wrong order, first define your model, compile it and then initialize. Same code, just different order

Comment: I defined the model and compiled it then i initialized the model but the error become : 
"Attempting to use uninitialized value W_c_1"     
instead of       
"Attempting to use uninitialized value bn6/beta"

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. Forget about the session when using keras, it only complicates things.

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

command_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,1))
image_measurements_features = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1, 640))

command_module_layer1 = keras.layers.Dense(128 ,activation='relu')(command_input)
command_module_layer2 = keras.layers.Dense(128 ,activation='relu')(command_module_layer1)

j = keras.layers.concatenate([command_module_layer2, image_measurements_features])

desicion_module_layer1 = keras.layers.Dense(512,activation='relu')(j)
desicion_module_layer2 = keras.layers.Dense(256,activation='relu')(desicion_module_layer1)
desicion_module_layer3 = keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu')(desicion_module_layer2)
desicion_module_layer4 = keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='relu')(desicion_module_layer3)

big_hero_4 = keras.models.Model(inputs=[command_input, image_measurements_features], outputs=desicion_module_layer4)
big_hero_4.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])

# Mock data
x = np.zeros((1, 1, 1))
y = np.zeros((1, 1, 640))
z = np.zeros((1, 1, 3))

historyy=big_hero_4.fit([x, y], z, batch_size=None, epochs=1,steps_per_epoch=1000)
```

This code should start training with no issues. If you still have the same error it might be due to some other part of your code if there is more.